# Simple ASP function question

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp-classic

Good Morning,

I have got the following function:

```
 FUNCTION queryDatabaseCount(sqlStr)
        SET queryDatabaseCountRecordSet = databaseConnection.Execute(sqlStr) 
        If queryDatabaseCountRecordSet.EOF Then
            queryDatabaseCountRecordSet.Close
            queryDatabaseCount = 0
        Else
            QueryArray = queryDatabaseCountRecordSet.GetRows
            queryDatabaseCountRecordSet.Close
            queryDatabaseCount = UBound(QueryArray,2) + 1
        End If
    END FUNCTION
```

And the following dbConnect:

```
SET databaseConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    databaseConnection.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source ="&dataSource&"; Initial Catalog ="&initialCatalog&"; User Id ="&userID&"; Password="&password&""
```

But for some reason I get the following error:

```
ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78'
```

Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

/UBS/DBMS/includes/blocks/block_databaseoverview.asp, line 30

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Many Thanks, 
Joel

Comment: Where is that you're including the dbConnect? It will need to be included before the block_databaseoverview.asp gets included.

Comment: Line 30 is: 
 If queryDatabaseCountRecordSet.EOF Then

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that is Line 30?

That error message is typically what you would get on the database.Execute(sqlStr) statement, if the connection is not open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long time since I touched asp/ado but I have some vague memory about EOF not always being a reliable indicator:

```
If (rst.BOF And rst.EOF) Then
--
Else
--
End If
```

As an aside, you shouldn't really be determining a record count that way. Preferably execute a statement or proc that returns only the count, rather than returning the rows then counting them.

Comment: That sounds more reasonable any idea how I could achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As already been pointed out: use a count in stead of your code (your code will load all data in memory!)

```
function queryDatabaseCount(sTable, sSomeCondition) 
   dim sSql
   dim Result
   Result = 0
   sSql = "select Count(*) as Cnt from " & sTable
   if sSomeCondition <> "" then
      sSql = sSql & " where " &  sSomeCondition
   end if
   objRec.Source = sSql
   objRec.Open
   Result = Fld("Cnt")
   objRec.Close
   queryDatabaseCount = Result
```

end function

calling it as

```
dim i
SET databaseConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
SET objRec = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRec.ActiveConnection = databaseConnection 

i = queryDatabaseCount("MyTable", "SomeField = 1")

databaseConnection.Close
SET databaseConnection = nothing
```

Haven't tested this code, but it should do the trick (or come very close to the solution).

Just as a side note: I tend to append the suffix _DBO to these function (meaning Data Base Open), letting me know that this function expects a open database connection. But that's just personal preference of course.